# Bluetooth headset mic with windproofing for recording audio whilst cycling

Tags: microphone

I'm planning on experimenting with producing a video / audio commentary whilst cycling and wondering what options might be out there for a bluetooth headset mic with windproofing that could be attached to a recorder. Something similar to channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgef_fFE9FEFZGQcHqp9aZw on youtube but on a bicycle and hopefully better quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you wear full-face helmets? In that case, the helmet itself would block most of the wind noise. You would also need to contend with your own breathing (which I assume might start to get heavy as you cycle). Lastly you need to consider the movement of the mic as you move. I think you're on the right track with a Bluetooth headset, because then you don't have the cord rubbing and creating noise, and you can also anchor it to your face with some tape or something.

You should keep in mind that because Bluetooth headsets are usually used in conjunction with phones (which filter out frequencies to lower bandwidth), they don't usually have great quality until you get to the expensive ones.

Lastly, the link you put up is pretty great quality for being on a motorcycle with that much air pressure going past.

This might be a good choice. It says there are "Six layers of our unique WindSmart® technology detect wind direction and respond accordingly so your voice comes through clearly –especially outdoors" as well as "Cutting Edge Noise Cancelling: Features four microphones and a proprietary DSP that work together to cancel disruptive background noise like traffic or crowds" :
[https://www.amazon.com/Plantronics-Voyager-5200-Bluetooth-Headset/dp/B01H2RBQUG?SubscriptionId=AKIAIOIL6HT4RMUFB3AA&tag=pcm_rounduptable-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01H2RBQUG&ascsubtag=83eca1f3-abd1-496d-bf05-3ded72e21dfd](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01H2RBQUG)

As for actually recording, this is the only halfway decent recorder with bluetooth that I could find:
[https://www.amazon.com/Olympus-V414151BU000-Linear-LS-P2-Recorder/dp/B019G7VMG8/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1506194874&sr=1-1&refinements=p_n_feature_keywords_three_browse-bin%3A6027146011](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019G7VMG8)

You might want to look up "lapel" or "lavelier" mics which are geared towards actual recording rather than communications. However, this way will also most likely cost more, and require a little more consideration on how to carry the pieces. You will need to have the bodypack somewhere, then the receiver in your backpack (for example), and then a recorder hooked up to the receiver.
Here's a bunch of lavs:
https://www.sweetwater.com/c994--Lavalier_Wireless_Systems